# I want to show some text when i click on an image and hide it if i click on it or on any other images

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, web

I want to show some text when I click on an image and hide it if I click on it again or on any other image, how to do it?

**[Example](http://www.forbo.com/corporate/en-gl/).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply keep your `text` bottom of your `img` and wrap it with `div` or `p` tag. Then initially make it `display:none`.

**Dummy HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
  <img src="" />
  <p style="display:none;">Your text here</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <img src="" />
  <p style="display:none;">Your text here</p>
</div>
```

Then your `script` will something like (using jQuery):

```
$('.content').click(function(){
   $('.content p').fadeOut();
   $(this).find('p').fadeIn();
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: if I want to keep those two images in one row, and on click it should fadeout taking the whole space of the row.... as I have share a link in my question?

Comment: you want show something exactly like the reference site? yes, it's possible..

Comment: Yes. I have put the images in a row,but stuck at showing the text as the reference site. I want to achieve the same functionality as the site foe images... can you help

Comment: Check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aRahmanS29/9Lu92qoL/. i've used `div` instead of `img`.

Comment: JSFiddle Updated with close button: http://jsfiddle.net/aRahmanS29/9Lu92qoL/1/. Don't forget to accept this answer if this help you :)

Comment: thank you for your replay... the div is not hidden when we click on it for nxt time... can you toggle between show and hide on click

Comment: inside click function, you can use `toggleClass` to make this `div` hidden. something like: `$('your-div').toggleClass('hide-div');` then make `display:none;` for `.hide-div`. Hope it works!